# Remote API for application code updating

Tags: docker

I'm using the java client and working with remote api on a limited implementation so far. My goal is to use a since image to spin up multiple containers then dynamically enable those containers to access a host directly that has developer code. In this case it is a container running Tomcat and .war files.

I don't want to include the .war files in the images since that would created hundreds of images. Via the command line I can copy a .war into a container, which could okay but there doesn't seem to be an option for that in the remote api. Ideally, I would like to make mounts points available for the container to use and that the developer can continuously update their code. If that's possible it would be great, but as of yet I haven't found the right combination. I have tried HostConfig : Binds:["/host/path:/container/path"] which shows up in the container info but doesn't seem to do what I wish. Any and all help would be greatly appreciate.

Below is the java method I use to create the container.

```
public int doIt(){

    int ri = 0;

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject aObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject bObject = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    try {
    object.put("Image", "test/tomcat");

    aObject.put("/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps", new JSONObject());
    object.put("Volumes", aObject);

    list.add("/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps");
    bObject.put("Binds",list);
    object.put("HostConfig", bObject);



    System.out.println("object.toString before try " + object.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 

         HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.97:4243/containers/create?name=");
         StringEntity params = new StringEntity(object.toString());
         request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            System.out.println("Response Code : " 
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            ri = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return ri;
}
```

Below is the inspect of the container created by the method.

```
[
{
    "Id": "d725ec70fd0edb012850f031faf6e50c7362491db1165c7b69684259529d124c",
    "Created": "2016-06-05T00:40:56.0745768Z",
    "Path": "catalina.sh",
    "Args": [
        "run"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "created",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:50630603d091a8a26abbf7e136a588a956a236a3f0ee4433d3bdb4968987b22a",
    "ResolvConfPath": "",
    "HostnamePath": "",
    "HostsPath": "",
    "LogPath": "",
    "Name": "/romantic_dijkstra",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "StorageOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "BlkioIOps": 0,
        "BlkioBps": 0,
        "SandboxSize": 0
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps",
            "Destination": "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Name": "0bc51a207c05837c276dce77d697412715616c8353cb8d6fef3cfcb3ba5b3d3e",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/0bc51a207c05837c276dce77d697412715616c8353cb8d6fef3cfcb3ba5b3d3e/_data",
            "Destination": "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "d725ec70fd0e",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre",
            "JAVA_VERSION=7u101",
            "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=7u101-2.6.6-1~deb8u1",
            "CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat",
            "TOMCAT_MAJOR=7",
            "TOMCAT_VERSION=7.0.69",
            "TOMCAT_TGZ_URL=https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.69/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.69.tar.gz"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "catalina.sh",
            "run"
        ],
        "Image": "test/tomcat",
        "Volumes": {
            "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/tomcat",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": null,
        "SandboxKey": "",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "",
                "EndpointID": "",
                "Gateway": "",
                "IPAddress": "",
                "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Sorry for taking up so much space.

The string that the java creates is below.

```
{"Image":"test\/tomcat","HostConfig":{"Binds":["\/home\/mkwalter\/tomcat\/webapps:\/usr\/local\/tomcat\/webapps"]},"Volumes":{"\/home\/mkwalter\/tomcat\/webapps":{}}}
```

Response Code : 201

Comment: not sure about the problem, are u not able to mount a volume using remote API or do you want an approach

Comment: I'm unable to mount a volume on the host machine though I seem to be doing everything syntactically correct.

Comment: Can you share ur code?

Comment: I've updated my original question with the code I use and the inspect of the container that is created. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Awesome, can you add the json string you are printing with sysout

Comment: Also I see two mounts, one seems intentional and the other looks incorrectly defined, this could be because of the json posted to the api when you are making the request.  Also using java client is not a hugely bad idea, you may already know but you can check the wiki with sample code using the java sdk for docker https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Your current JSON is of the format

```js
{
  "Image": "test/tomcat",
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
      "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps"
    ]
  },
  "Volumes": {
    "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps": {

    }
  }
}
```

You Should be posting a request of the format

```js
{
  "Image": "test/tomcat",
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
      "/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps"
    ]
  },
  "Volumes": {
    "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps":{}
  }
}
```

here is the code update u will need to make to fix this

```js
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject aObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject bObject = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    try {
    object.put("Image", "test/tomcat");

    aObject.put("/usr/local/tomcat/webapps", new JSONObject());
    object.put("Volumes", aObject);

    list.add("/home/mkwalter/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps");
    bObject.put("Binds",list);
    object.put("HostConfig", bObject);
```

Comment: I've updated the original question including your suggestion.

Comment: I had specified wrong format for the Volumes, I have corrected that and tested it using tomcat docker container.

Comment: So, what's your new format and code you used to create it?